# Web Api do not support authorization_code grant type:oauth2-resource-server and oauth2-client in single app as web_application_and_resource_server

Tags: azure-active-directory, spring-boot-starter-oauth2-client

I am trying to configure `spring-boot-starter-oauth2-resource-server` and `spring-boot-starter-oauth2-client` in a single app as `web_application_and_resource_server`. After [following these instructions](https://github.com/Azure-Samples/azure-spring-boot-samples/blob/main/aad/azure-spring-boot-starter-active-directory/aad-web-application-and-resource-server/src/main/java/com/azure/spring/sample/aad/security/AADWebApplicationAndResourceServerConfig.java) I have the following error:

```
Error: Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Web Api do not support authorization_code grant type. id = graph.
```

I am unsure how to configure the properties for the resource server, I tried the properties below:

```
azure.activedirectory.tenant-id=###
# Specifies your App Registration's Application ID:
azure.activedirectory.client-id=###
# Specifies your App Registration's secret key:
azure.activedirectory.client-secret=###
azure.activedirectory.application-type = web_application_and_resource_server
#azure.activedirectory.app-id-uri=##
#azure.activedirectory.authorization-clients.api.authorizationGrantType=on_behalf_of
#azure.activedirectory.authorization-clients.api.scopes=https://graph.microsoft.com/User.Read
azure.activedirectory.authorization-clients.graph.authorizationGrantType=authorization_code
azure.activedirectory.authorization-clients.graph.scopes=https://graph.microsoft.com/User.Read,Directory.AccessAsUser.All,offline_access,openid,profile,email
```

**How does the configuration apply to resource server?**
With above configuration I receive an error `webapi cant accept authorisation code as a granttype` which is true.

**Is there any specific configuration required at AZure Ad level?**
All APIs are within the spring boot application itself. I just need all APIs to be authenticated using the token.